# Cost of pin insulators

Tags: power-supply, voltage, high-voltage, power-engineering

[image]

H. Cotton's *Transmission and Distribution of Electrical Energy* states that the cost of pin insulators increases exponentially with voltage. Why is this, and why isn't it linear?

Comment: Uff. He didn't cite anyone on that? That's a very steep claim, and honestly, that book is from 1958, so, unless someone else agrees, I'd just ... disregard it. Maybe try to figure out actual 2022 retail prices of these things.

Comment: Here's the thing, the textbooks I've read say that pin insulators are uneconomical at over 33kV. Why is it so?

Comment: The quoted material doesn't actually claim exponential, just some power > 2. Simple material considerations would suggest a cube law. Consider : to increase the voltage while maintaining field strength (V/M) you need to increase dimension linearly with voltage. Now consider the material strength required to support a linear increase in height : you'll need to increase diameter too. Increase it linearly (simply scaling) increases the volume of material as the cube of length (and voltage). Presumably the book's purposes don't require any more detail than that.

Comment: Is it the same for suspension insulators then?

Answer (score 4):

**33 kV** seems to still be an accurate limit for the **four-piece (4) pin-type insulators** [ref typical mfg in China](https://www.hbjinyong.com/insulator/pin-insulator/) due to the exponential weight with increasing diameters in 4 pc's.

- the cost factor is likely much greater than a power of 2 from the ratios of material weight from doubling the voltage,  the weight can be more 5x (see below)
- **For a linear expansion, the surface area is a 2nd order effect with radius and 3rd order effect with volume.**

Why is radius important?

Answer: To reduce the accumulation of ionized water, an umbrella effect is needed to increase the creepage distance. This is done by the ratio of outer to inner radius and affects the surface breakdown voltage from moisture.  **Dust in the air and rain degrades these breakdown threshold voltages even worse from ion conduction. Wet tests, however, use clean water**

This answer leads to many more questions and answers to fully understand why creepage  path length in kV/mm is determined by the radius which affects those test results.  In effect, a larger diameter offers a partial air gap which is may have less contamination than the surface. This increases the weight significantly and cost.  The alternative is to have more than four-pieces pin with small diameters, **but stronger to ensure the same physical reliability.**

One can evaluate the creepage distance ratio with the creepage voltage test rating ratios below in the table for 2 different styles of insulators ( and costs) comparing 15kV with 33kV for an almost power of 2.

One valid test method is the onset of partial discharge (PD) for creepage voltage by measuring the early warning of Radio Frequency Noise from surface discharge arcs. This is called the [Radio Influence (from interference) Voltage (RIV) threshold](http://www.arresterworks.com/resources/arrester_dictionary/arrester_r/radio_influence_voltage.php). This must be much higher than the "safe" rated insulation voltage rating and the ratio of RIV to Vmax is an indicator of the creepage ratio to gap of the pure insulator between the nearest metal conductors which has some kV/mm rating.

[image]
[image]

Bushing insulators in transformers you will find are rated for voltage with a minimum of 2 criteria. The **standard voltage rating** and the Basic Impulse Level (BIL) for impulses due to lightning. Thus BIL 100 is rated for 100kV impulse defined by a standard risetime and duration which can withstand a much higher voltage due to the time it takes to ionize air in microseconds.

### Trivia

The RIV name came from the common interference of AM and SW radios driving under old power lines with insufficient creepage ratings during the 1940s to 80's. It would interfere with AM reception due to the extreme buzzing noise.
Even today with modern insulators, you can still hear some bushing insulators with acoustic buzz from dew or humidity and dust contamination.  When the power cables are shielded coaxial types the AM radio interference is greatly reduced and often not noticed. This became common with the invention of crosslinked polymer insulation created by UHV (GV's) to zap any contamination with partial discharge and cross-link the plastic polymers to improve strength (tires) and greatly increase breakdown voltage rating.

### Links

https://www.theengineerspost.com/types-of-insulators/
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/what-are-the-types-of-insulators-used-in-transmission-lines
https://www.electrical4u.com/types-of-electrical-insulator-overhead-insulator/

Comment: What about suspension type or strain type insulators

Comment: What about them? Same deal different mechanical. You need more rings to scale up voltage since the cost of each ring is exponentially limited.  33kV seems to be common. Did you understand my answer? if not why?

Comment: I found this to help you understand https://www.tutorialspoint.com/what-are-the-types-of-insulators-used-in-transmission-lines

Comment: One comment under my question says that the increased radius is for mechanical support and your answer says that it's for preventing contamination on the underside

Comment: Compare the shape and dimensions of d and D for 15kV & 33kV between lightweight on the left and heavy on right,.  The fatter one has a couple more underside ribs to increase creepage distance and thus creepage rating.  Thickness adds mass which then increases the strength requirement for the radius of threaded mass radius d1. So you could say both are true.  But creepage needs are due to surface contamination where the underside is preferable. The other factor is to avoid sharp edges which increase E-field gradient

Comment: Compare the lowest kg weight of 2kg/15kV to the most 13kg/33kV.  The reason for this exponential variance is the creepage and BIL ratings not mechanical support strength which is pretty much constant for bending load.

Comment: Your answer says "The alternative is to have more than four-pieces pin with small diameters, but stronger to ensure the same physical reliability" Why isn't this done? as opposed to using suspension or strain type insulators

Comment: Mechanical insulators vary by design for compression or expansion, interface and insulation voltage. But this question was limited to 4 pc pins only. with some practical mechanical limits